# How to measure random/sequential read/write on Linux. SSD considerations

Tags: linux, solid-state-drive

I wish to purchase an SSD drive for my Linux Fedora 16 work station.
It will be mainly used for web development over Gnome3, IDE and a virtual server (for the web env).

I have two candidates.

- crucial m4 128gb ( have much better 4k random read )
- SanDisk extreme 3 120GB ( much faster in sequential and writes )

I wonder what will benefit my system most and if there is a tool to measure the actual random/sequential read/write on my system.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a better question for [so], since [su] is more for programming, & [so] is more for using & optimizing systems?

Comment: Check out hdparm and fio. See more details here- https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance/991311#991311

Answer (score 2):

yout can try the commercial version tool named [PassMark BurnInTest™](http://www.passmark.com/products/bit.htm). The neweset version is BurnInTest 7.1.

also you can try the Freeware [AS SSD Benchmark 1.7.4739.38088](http://www.alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?cat_id=4&download_id=9)
Both **BurnInTest**(also available for Linux) ) and **AS SSD Benchmark** is for Windows Platform.
There is some utility under linux:  [Several I/O benchmark options exist under Linux.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD_Benchmarking#Introduction)

> 1. Using hddparm with the -Tt switch, one can time sequential reads. This method is independent of partition alignment!
> 2. There is a graphical benchmark called gnome-disks contained in the gnome-disk-utility package that will give min/max/ave reads along with
>      ave access time and a nice graphical display. This method is
>      independent of partition alignment!
> 3. The dd utility can be used to measure both reads and writes. This method is dependent on partition alignment! In other words, if you
>      failed to properly align your partitions, this fact will be seen here
>      since you're writing and reading to a mounted filesystem.
> 4. Bonnie++

And if your want do more control of the benchmark, I recommand you to use [**SMARTCTL**](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartctl.8.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actual system RAM is faster, & cheaper ;)  Then go for the fastest system & program loading drive, IIRC that would be the 4k speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my benchmark described in the following that also has link to download the program:

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linux_disk_usb_lan_benchmarks.htm

Latest version includes random writing. Example results are below. A run time parameter can select larger files.

```
 ###############################################################

 Selected File Path: 
 /media/PAT//
 Total MB    7620, Free MB    7620, Used MB       0

 Linux Storage Speed Test 64-Bit Version 1.2, Tue Dec 10 16:08:20 2013

                Copyright (C) Roy Longbottom 2012

     8 MB File         1          2          3          4          5
 Writing MB/sec       5.18      11.97      12.12      12.04      11.96
 Reading MB/sec      30.88      31.57      31.60      31.45      29.22

    16 MB File         1          2          3          4          5
 Writing MB/sec      11.90      11.95      12.26      12.07      12.14
 Reading MB/sec      30.94      31.47      31.51      31.51      30.31

    32 MB File         1          2          3          4          5
 Writing MB/sec      11.97      12.07      12.11      12.15      12.18
 Reading MB/sec      31.26      31.49      31.52      31.50      30.90

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 8 MB Cached File      1          2          3          4          5
 Writing MB/sec     396.50      77.49      11.19      11.01      13.36
 Reading MB/sec    2810.03    2675.62    2972.66    3139.78    3079.33

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bus Speed Block KB     64        128        256        512       1024
 Reading MB/sec      28.34      28.31      30.25      31.00      31.41

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 KB Blocks File MB >    2      4      8     16     32     64    128
 Random Read  msecs    0.52   0.51   0.50   0.50   0.50   0.50   0.52
 Random Write msecs    5.47   5.56   3.31   8.48   3.35   3.35 194.27

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 500 Files   Write             Read             Delete
 File KB     MB/sec  ms/File   MB/sec  ms/File  Seconds
       2       0.09    22.35     3.07     0.67    0.014
       4       0.15    26.79     6.12     0.67    0.014
       8       0.35    23.43     9.94     0.82    0.014
      16       0.74    22.12    16.16     1.01    0.014
      32       1.59    20.61    22.12     1.48    0.015
      64       3.03    21.66    28.06     2.34    0.015
```